# Rounding time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am trying to figure out a formula to calculate the fraction of an hour. I want to break up an hour into six-minute intervals. This means I would have the following table:

```
Input                             Output
-----                             ------
5 hrs 0 mins                      5.0
5 hrs 1 min                       5.0
5 hrs 2 mins                      5.0
5 hrs 3 mins                      5.0

5 hrs 4 mins                      5.1
5 hrs 5 mins                      5.1
5 hrs 6 mins                      5.1
5 hrs 7 mins                      5.1
5 hrs 8 mins                      5.1
5 hrs 9 mins                      5.1

5 hrs 10 mins                     5.2
5 hrs 11 mins                     5.2
5 hrs 12 mins                     5.2
5 hrs 13 mins                     5.2
5 hrs 14 mins                     5.2
5 hrs 15 mins                     5.2

5 hrs 16 mins                     5.3
...
```

Currently, I have the following:

```
var d = new Date();
var h = d.getHours(); 
var m = d.getMinutes();
var fraction = Math.floor(m / 60);

var result = h + '.' + fraction;
```

The fraction part is not working right. There is something about rounding, etc. that I'm not sure how to handle in this situation. I would be thankful for anyone that can help me with this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Well "m" is always going to be less than 60, so `m / 60` will always be a fraction. Calling `.floor()` with that will therefore always produce 0. What if you instead divided by `6`, since that's the unit you're interested in?

Comment: `fraction = (m/60).toFixed(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply a little logic to properly [format a duration with javascript](http://www.ecofic.com/about/blog/format-duration-in-google-sheet-with-javascript). The logic is needed to consider the final minutes in an hour. The following should work for you:

```
function FormatDuration(duration) { 
  // Retrieve the hours and minutes
  var hrs = duration.getHours();
  var mins = duration.getMinutes();

  // Convert the minutes to a fraction of an hour.
  var tenths = ((mins / 60).toFixed(1) * 10);
  if (tenths === 10) {
    tenths = 0;
    hrs = hrs + 1;
  }
  return hrs + '.' + tenths;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dividing by 60 will always give you a value between 0 and 1, meaning `floor()` will always return 0 (unless `m` is equal to `60`). You can divide by 6 instead:

```
var fraction = Math.floor(m / 6);
```

Tests:

```
Math.floor(6 / 6);     // 1
Math.floor(3 / 6);     // 0
Math.floor(30 / 6);    // 5
Math.floor(59 / 6);    // 9
```

Comment: Don't feel bad - I had to try it on a piece of paper to make sure I was getting it right :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is correct but this seems to match your numbers:

```
var fraction = Math.round(m/6.1) / 10;
```

I used 6.1 to push the numbers down one as with just 6 3 minutes becomes .1 instead of 4 minutes becoming .1

This leads to 58 and 59 minutes being a whole 1.0 which would bump up your hours to the next. Not sure if that is what you want as your samples only go up to 16 minutes.

I came up with this by playing in excel with the numbers from 0 to 59. It's a great way to test these types of issues.